# Unity3D C# get the total number of a specific 3D Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working in a `Unity3D` project and in a `C#` script, I want to know the total number of `Cube`?

Comment: please do a bit of research. it really isnt that difficult https://www.google.com/webhp?q=count+game+objects+unity+by+name

Comment: It's not the same, I want the result for specific type, not for a specific name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
var cubes = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Cube));
var count = cubes.Length;
```

This is assuming you have attached a script called 'Cube' to your cubes.

Alternatively, you can tag the cube objects and find by tag:

```
var cubes = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("cubeTag");
```

Comment: Do I need a using? It telling my that the namespace name 'Cube' couldn't be found

Comment: If it's possible, I want to avoid to find byt tag because I have many tags for my cubes.

Comment: No, I don't have a script that is common for all my cubes. Plus, your code isn't working: "The name 'FindObjectsWithTag' does not exist int the current context".

Comment: @FélixLD To Unity, all your cubes are simply game objects. I would suggest adding something common to all your cubes. Instead of having various tags for your cubes, the properties could be stored in an attached script.

Comment: Like an empty objects that would contains all my cubes?

Comment: @FélixLD Do you mean attaching an empty script of the same type to all your cubes? That could work.

Comment: No, I already have script on some cubes, but I mean create a GameObject empty... by select: Create > Create Empty